# 3D Surface Related Multiple Elmination (SRME)

Tags: geophysics, signal-processing, imaging

Let's assume we are looking at first order multiples of the same surface (i.e no peg leg, etc). I am looking at marine 3D SRME and I am a little confused as to how this works. I understand that in the 2D sense, you can interpolate between two source points to calculate the source point of your reflection point and then you can go about doing your convolutions to create your multiple model, however I don't understand how this works in the 3D sense as you don't have a source point every where along your 3D survey.

How do you therefore choose your free surface reflection point to generate your "secondary primary" wavelet to do your SRME?

If you want me to clarify ANYTHING, please ask as I really need an answer ASAP. Also, if this is the wrong place for this question, could you please direct me to the correct SE website, thank you.

Comment: Would http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic It's not really a computer science question though, is it. It's a seismic image processing question. I don't know if that counts as "signal processing" in the same sense as Signal Processsing SE, does it? I could ask there...

Comment: I think it's on-topic here since you're asking a data-analysis question tied to the physical phenomenon you're trying to reveal. But on-topic doesn't mean you'll get the best/quickest answer here... another SE site might generate a faster response but I can't say for sure.